# TPL - are PLINQ queries ordered by default?

Tags: .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

In a few podcasts I listened to discussing PLINQ, the original idea was to provide unordered queries by default for perfromance reasons and the dev could decide to make it ordered if that was important. But then it was stated that this was going to be changed to be ordered by default and devs who wanted extra performance and didn't care about order could make it unordered.

All examples and docs i've seen use .AsOrdered() which leads me to believe that it's unordered by default still.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are absolutely unordered by default and that's exactly why `AsOrdered` exists. Using `AsOrdered` introduces an extra-step and, thus, extra-overhead, to take the results from the disparate worker threads and get them into proper order. Also, if it's not obvious, `AsOrdered` is blocking (see update below) which means results will not progress through the PLINQ query pipeline until items have arrived in the order they original started in.

Finally, note that `AsUnordered` exists so that you can switch the query back to a non-ordered query from that point forward in the query pipeline.

**UPDATE:**

I just want to clarify what I mean by "blocking". What happens is that PLINQ has to observe the original order of the elements at the point when they are handed to the ParallelQuery. From there it will ensure that elements that complete before elements out of order are **buffered**. So if you have elements in order like "one", "two", "three" and "two" finishes before "one", "two" will be buffered until "one" is completed.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware of the blocking aspect. Do you know why they didn't default it to ordered?

Comment: Because in a parallel world you want as little coupling between the disparate data elements as possible. Once you say you need order that implies the elements are somehow related. So they defaulted to unordered for the expectations of most parallel programmers and added AsOrdered as an explicit call for those who actually need it.

Comment: @DustinDavis because it hurts performance. For something that is used when performance is important (like PLINQ), that's counter to the purpose of it. In many cases, order isn't important at all. If it is, *then* incur the performance hit.

Comment: Perfect. That makes absolute sense when thinking in the context of work items that should be asynchronous and not dependant on other work items. Ordering would be an exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 1):

PLINQ will not order your results unless you specify `AsOrdered`. Since Parallel LINQ will execute work concurrently, it may finish the second item before the first.

Say you have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar() {return something;}
}
```

Let's say `Bar` on different instances of `Foo` takes an indeterminate amount of time to complete because it checks a file. So say we have a case where item A's `Bar` takes 10 seconds to complete, but item B's takes 1. Since B finished first, it ends up on top.

.NET won't order it by default because it needs to complete items in order before moving on to the next one. You can't order what you don't know. So for performance reasons, they are unordered by default. `AsOrdered` indicates order is important, but at the cost of blocking.